# Omit page number from parts pages

Tags: parts

I would like to:

1. omit the page number from parts pages
2. provide some changes in the title style of the part page.

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{usnomencl}%pour la nomenclature
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
```

Comment: A solution depends on the documentclass, which one are you using? Also, a package could hack in. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) for us. Having specific code to work with, helping you is much easier.

Comment: @Hamza.w: What changes do you want in the style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the page number in the part page is easy: just tell `memoir` to use the `empty` page style on it.

Removing “Part n” is a bit more difficult: it requires redefining the commands responsible for it.

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\part{Essai de partie}

\end{document}
```

I removed the unnecessary packages. Note that `titlesec` is not compatible with `memoir`. I'd also avoid `fncychap`: the `memoir` class provides several much better chapter styles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg could you please tell me more about memoir chapter styles

Comment: @Hamza.w Do `texdoc memoirchapstyles` or click here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf